# Updating a pandas dataframe and adding the missing lines considering a pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
Date         Scenario  Value
2018-08-08     S1       120
2018-08-08     S2       132
2018-08-08     S3       127
2018-08-09     S1       114
2018-08-09     S3       107
2018-08-09     S4       201
...
```

What I want to have is:

```
Date         Scenario  Value
2018-08-08     S1       120
2018-08-08     S2       132
2018-08-08     S3       127
2018-08-08     S4        0
2018-08-09     S1       114
2018-08-08     S2        0
2018-08-09     S3       107
2018-08-09     S4       201
...
```

So there is a pattern. For each day there are 4 scenarios. Each must be there! In case they are not there, I need to create a line with the missing date and scenario and assign `0` to the corresponding `Value` column. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do `pivot` then `stack`

```
s=df.pivot(*df.columns).stack(dropna=False).fillna(0).reset_index()
s
         Date Scenario      0
0  2018-08-08       S1  120.0
1  2018-08-08       S2  132.0
2  2018-08-08       S3  127.0
3  2018-08-08       S4    0.0
4  2018-08-09       S1  114.0
5  2018-08-09       S2    0.0
6  2018-08-09       S3  107.0
7  2018-08-09       S4  201.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it, is to define a df2 with your 2 first columns and then use:

```
pd.merge(df, df2, how='outer', on=['Date','Scenario']).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something very similar recently.

What you need is to use a pd.date_range, using the max date of how far you want your dates to go.

```
date_range = pd.date_range(start=min_date, end=max_date)
df = df.set_index('Date').reindex(date_range).fillna(0).rename_axis('Date').reset_index()
```

You have to make sure you're doing this at the most granular depth possible

Answer (score 0):

Create a list `l` of all posible `Scenario` values. Construct a multiindex `idx` from `l` and unique value of `df.Date`. Finally, `set_index` on `Date` and `Scenario` and reindex using `idx` and `reset_index`

```
l = ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4']
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.Date.unique(), l])
(df.set_index(['Date', 'Scenario']).reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
                                   .rename_axis(['Date', 'Scenarios'])
                                   .reset_index())

Out[498]:
         Date Scenarios  Value
0  2018-08-08        S1    120
1  2018-08-08        S2    132
2  2018-08-08        S3    127
3  2018-08-08        S4      0
4  2018-08-09        S1    114
5  2018-08-09        S2      0
6  2018-08-09        S3    107
7  2018-08-09        S4    201
```

---

Or another way is constructing a dataframe from `idx` above and merge `left` with `df` and `fillna`. However, this method is not as clean as `reindex` method above.